# How to validate a JSON list of dictionaries using Marshmallow in Python?

Tags: python, validation, marshmallow

How can I validate nestes json data using Marshmallow?

This was I came up with, currently I get:

`{'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}`
note sure why.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate 

class AuthUserSchema(Schema):
    user = fields.String()
    password = fields.String()
    enabled = fields.Boolean()

class AuthDataSchema(Schema):
    data = fields.List(fields.Nested(AuthUserSchema))

data = [
    {
        "enabled": True,
        "password": "6e5b5410415bde",
        "user": "admin"
    },
    {
        "enabled": True,
        "password": "4e5b5410415bde",
        "user": "guest"
    },
]

schema = AuthDataSchema()
errors = schema.validate(data)
print(errors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is causing issue -

```
errors = schema.validate(data)
```

Just modify it to -

```
errors = schema.validate({"data":data})
```

And now you can directly use `fields.Nested` -

```
data = fields.Nested(AuthUserSchema, many=True)
```

Comment: corrected:
errors = schema.validate({"data": data})

Comment: Yes, I have missed the `{}` braces. Let me update it

Comment: List(Nested) is preferred. We plan to deprecate Nested(many) but this won't happen tomorrow so you're fine both ways.